problem with import text in pdf by power query (right to left language)
if i convert ".pdf" to text  & use get data from ".txt" or ".csv" file & set file origin on "1256:Arabic (windows)", then i have a correct text in PQ.
else if i use directly get data from folder that contain ".pdf" file, then i have Not a correct text in PQ!!!
this is my M code:
let
    Source = #"Rep - PDF",
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Content", "Name"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each Text.Contains([Name], "سیویل")),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Name", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Name.1", "Name.2"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "read pdf", each Pdf.Tables([Content])),
    #"Expanded read pdf" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "read pdf", {"Id", "Name", "Kind", "Data"}, {"read pdf.Id", "read pdf.Name", "read pdf.Kind", "read pdf.Data"}),
    #"Expanded read pdf.Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded read pdf", "read pdf.Data", {"Column1"}, {"read pdf.Data.Column1"}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded read pdf.Data", "Cust", each Text.Combine(List.Reverse(Text.ToList([read pdf.Data.Column1])),"")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Right_to_left", each Character.FromNumber(8235)&[read pdf.Data.Column1]),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "chng_encod", each Text.FromBinary(Text.ToBinary([read pdf.Data.Column1],TextEncoding.Windows),1256))
in
    #"Added Custom3"


Can you share some data ?

you can test it on persian or arabic pdf on internet ...
